# How to make the script stop execution when an error occurres

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a Windows bat file with the following content:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Stop batch script loop if a command failed.

@echo OFF

FOR %%a in (x86 x86_64 armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a) do (
    set MY_ANDROID_BUILD_ABI=%%a
    FOR %%m in (debug release) DO (
        set MY_MODE=%%m
        echo !MY_MODE! -^> !MY_ANDROID_BUILD_ABI!
        cd D:\dev\libs\QT6.4\android\!MY_MODE!\!MY_ANDROID_BUILD_ABI!
        rem some further build commands go here
        cmake --build . --parallel && cmake --install .
   )
)
```

it iterates over build configurations and executes multiple commands inside nested loop to build some library.

How to make the script exit the loop and stop execution when an error occurres?

For example, the script should stop if a directory does not exist or `cmake` command failed.

Should I add

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    echo "Previous command execution failed."
    exit %ERRORLEVEL%
)
```

after each command?

Comment: You can use conditional operators `||` for instance. `cd /d "d:\some dir" || exit /b 1` the `||` operator acts as `or`

Comment: Just AAMOI, whereas setting a variable then using it with !delayedexpansion! is quite correct (although using the syntax `set "var=value"` is usually preferred on SO as it precludes hard-to-find errors caused by terminal spaces), you can use `%%m` in place of `!my_mode!` as long as `%%m` is in scope (ie. within the `for` loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to add some kind of error checking, since cmd doesn't have built-in exceptions. The full solution is to add after each command:

```
(command)
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo failure message, maybe to some log
    exit !ERRORLEVEL!
)
```

You can use the shorthand suggested in @Gerhard's comment:

```
(command) || (echo failure message& exit /b !ERRORLEVEL! )
```

In either case, beware of using `%ERRORLEVEL%`, as it's expanded too early. As your code correctly shows, use `!ERRORLEVEL!` (which requires `setlocal EnabledDelayedExpansion`), or use the special `if ERRORLEVEL 1` format.

Comment: Just as a side note, not all commands sets an errorlevel and `||` acts on both errorlevel and exit codes.

Comment: To my understanding, errorlevel and exit codes are the same. More specifically, any external-to-cmd command (.exe) returns an exit code, which in cmd parlance is called "errorlevel".

Comment: Not always though, See [this link](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html#:~:text=Error%20level%20vs%20Exit%20code,cases%20where%20they%20can%20differ.)

Comment: Hmmm, weird. I guess ss64 know what they say. I wish they'd elaborate about what are the "cases where they can differ".

Comment: I will provide you with aome examples later if you want to test it out.

Comment: @Gerhard - that would be great, maybe I'll edit my answer to indicate that as well